# Using a GeoPoint location and meters X/Y, how can a Longitude/Latitude be calculated?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have a little project I've been playing with (Android, GPS, mapping APIs), and I need to figure how to find a longitude/latitude/GeoPoint from a given longitude/latitude/GeoPoint with only knowing the meters/km longitude and latitude. e.g. I want to figure out where a point is from me, that I know is +1000 meters along the longitude and +1000 along the latitude.

It's a little different than the usual GeoPoint/distance questions you'll see, and it's not quite geo fencing radius related as the distance is X,Y meters/kms, and I don't have a bearing. (I could work out a bearing, but I don't have a suitable direct distance)

Basically, if I could reverse GeoPoint.distanceTo() it would do the job for me.

**Update**

Just a little more background. I'm basically applying a node triangulation idea I had, but the algorithm requires that my inputs be in a map normalized form that's not the same as longitude and latitude. I create a map/grid where 0,0 (the bottom/left) is the left/west and bottom/south most longitude/latitude values from the nodes I'm working with. All the other node X/Y on the map are determined by finding their meters from the 0,0 node's longitude/latitude using GeoPoint.distanceTo(). (note that I find their X/Y by performing distanceTo twice for each node so I have the X and Y meters from 0,0, not a direct line to the node) That distance in meters is fed into the algorithm and new X/Y map points are produced.

And so I need to figure out how to convert distance from a longitude/latitude into another, previously unknown, longitude/latitude.

```
double startPointLongitude = 23.459821;
double startPointLatitude = 76.998200;
double distanceLongitude = 100; // 100 meters along the longitude
double distanceLatitude = 75; // 75 meters along the latitude
```

Comment: Note that order matters, you will arrive at different points if you go north then east and east then north.

Comment: The problem is I'm not even sure if using a north and east bearing will work correctly. I believe that a compass doesn't perfectly align with the lines on which longitude and latitude run. Meaning latitude would run with the curve of the earth while north would be a direct line to a point. I could be wrong. but even if I whipped up a test, I wouldn't know if my results would be correct.

Comment: For hundreds of meters, you can convert the cartesian coordinates to [polar ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates). The error will be negligible. For greater distances you'll run into trouble, since the Earth is not a perfect sphere but an ellipsoid. GMaps use [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS84) as reference.

Comment: More info: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25494/how-accurate-is-approximating-the-earth-as-a-sphere

Comment: @Mister Smith: wrong, you cannot do that, because lat and lon have differnet scale (sclae factor = cos(latitude)

Answer (score 2):

Basically i took the Answer from AlexWien, corrected two things and made it into a java method

```
private static final double WGS84_RADIUS = 6370997.0;
private static double EarthCircumFence = 2* WGS84_RADIUS * Math.PI;

private static Position getPosition(Position sourcePosition, double mEastWest, double mNorthSouth){
    double degreesPerMeterForLat = EarthCircumFence/360.0;
    double shrinkFactor = Math.cos((sourcePosition.getLat()*Math.PI/180));
    double degreesPerMeterForLon = degreesPerMeterForLat * shrinkFactor;
    double newLat = sourcePosition.getLat() + mNorthSouth * (1/degreesPerMeterForLat);
    double newLng = sourcePosition.getLng() + mEastWest * (1/degreesPerMeterForLon);
    return new Position(newLat, newLng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two degrees of latitude never change, it is always aprox. 111 km
(The exact value you should caculate by using the WGS84 Earth radius:

```
 EarthCircumFence = 2* WGS84_RADIUS * Math.Pi;
```

metersPerDegree = (Earth Cirumfence / 360)

With this info you easily can calculate the latitude offset,
just reverse the factor and have:

```
degreesPerMeterForLat = EarthCircumfenceMeter / 360.0
```

with longitude its a bit different, the distance between two degrees of longitude shrink 
the more you move away from aequator.

```
shrinkFactor = cos(toRadians(locationLatitude));
```

compensate now:

```
degreesPerMeterForLon = degreesPerMeterForLat / shrinkFactor;
```

Finally

```
newLatPos = latOld + numMeters * degreesPerMeterForLat;
newLonPos = lonOld + numMeters * degreesPerMeterForLon;
```

This works for distance offset < 10 - 50 km

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. Its basically what I was looking for, but I managed to come to a similar conclusion in my answer earlier today. For some reason my answer didn't post and I didn't notice until now. BTW, Wikipedia and other references (UCSB http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/giscc/units/u014/u014.html) indicate that 1 degree of latitude at the equator is 111.329 kms.

Comment: the value depends on the used earth circumfense, you should use the WGS84 Earth radius, then calulate circumfence. 111.111 is 40.000 km / 360; not exact (but it would practiclally not affect the distance calculation)

Answer (score 0):

*Sigh, I posted this like 6 hours ago but it does not appear to have gone through.*

Ok, worked it out in spite of most geographical formulas and facts occasionally going over my head. Working with geography is like working with the Gregorian calendar, it makes sense if you program for it all the time, but otherwise it's easy to get confused by an incorrect assumption.

The following except from my app will take a starting GeoPoint's long/lat

```
   /**
    * the length of one degree of latitude (and one degree of longitude at equator) in meters.
    */
   private static final double DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR = 111329;


   /**
    * calculates the x,y in meters from a given starting point's long0, lat0 to a target destination point's long1, lat1.
    * @param long0 start point longitude
    * @param lat0 start point latitude
    * @param long1 end point longitude
    * @param lat1 end point latitude
    * @return
    */
   public static Pair<Double, Double> xyFromLongLat(int long0, int lat0, int long1, int lat1) {
    double x = (long1 / 1E6 - long0 / 1E6) * longitudeDistanceAtLatitude(lat0 / 1E6);
    double y = (lat1 / 1E6 - lat0 / 1E6) * DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR;
    return new Pair<Double, Double>(x, y);
   }

   /**
    * calculates longitude and latitude from a given starting point, with only the X/Y meters 
    * @param long0
    * @param lat0
    * @param x
    * @param y
    * @return
    */
   public static Pair<Double, Double> longLatFromXY(int long0, int lat0, double x, double y) {
        double lat1 = (y / DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR) + (lat0 / 1E6);
        double long1 = x / longitudeDistanceAtLatitude(lat0) + (long0 / 1E6);
        return new Pair<Double, Double>(lat1, long1);
   }
```

Comment: The most important thing is missing in this post: longitudeDistanceAtLatitude. Your post Shows your code, but isnot an answer, since it confuses more;  You use microDegrees for longitude without commenting that, in the javadoc. Further it does not explain anything.